# Как автоматически заносить данные в базу данных?

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, django, sqlite3

У меня есть словарь, который постоянно обновляется. Словарь по типу {'Заголовок новости':'Текст новости'}. Как мне автоматически из этого словаря заносить данные с помощью Django в базу данных sqlite3?

Comment: Напиши менеждмент команду и запусти её в планировщик

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создать свой класс который будет наследоваться от класс dict и переопределить методы доступа к словарю. Либо написать свой собственный класс. Хотя самым лучшем способом будет использовать какую либо ORM например SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Можно пример кода?

Comment: SQLAlchemy на мой взгляд является лучшем решением введение можно почитать https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/intro.html. А по переопределения методов лучше всего почитать в интернете, но данный подход требует понимания ООП и модели классов в Python